# How to organize CSS - table columns

Tags: html, css

Within my Web application are numerous pages that display tabular data (typically lists of objects with roughly 5 properties being displayed per object).

Each table has different needs for column widths.  I am using CSS to specify the widths but I'm concerned that my approach is going to lead to a bloated CSS file.

Here's an example of what I have...

```
table.mytblname2 td.stuff { width: 10%; }
table.mytblname2 td.this { width: 10%; }
table.mytblname2 td.that { width: 10%; }
table.mytblname2 td.something { width: 70%; }

table.mytblname3 td.anothercol { width: 25%; }
table.mytblname3 td.stuff { width: 25%; }
table.mytblname3 td.foo { width: 20%; }
table.mytblname3 td.bar { width: 20%; }
table.mytblname3 td.something { width: 10%; }
```

The way I see it, *class="anothercol"* and *style="width: 20%"* use exactly the same number of characters so I'm potentially using more bandwidth by bloating my CSS file in this particular scenario.

**Is this something that can be improved?  How?**

The application is using ASP.NET MVC 2 and I need to be cross-browser compatible down to IE6 and avoid making it unreadable when users have JavaScript disabled.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the approach I ended up taking (derived from answers from ddagradi and Jason).

```
table.data { width: 100%; ... etc ... }
table.data td, table.data th { padding: 4px; border: ... etc ... }

table.data th.w10 { width: 10%; }
table.data th.w20 { width: 20%; }
table.data th.w30 { width: 30%; }
table.data th.w40 { width: 40%; }
... etc ...

<table class="data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="w20">Date</th>
      <th class="w40">Name</th>
      <th class="w40">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My CSS file is MUCH cleaner and I can tell in the HTML what the width is.  I control common styling of the td/th through "table.data td" and "table.data th".  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a table will try to give all columns a uniform width, with priority given to columns with longer content. If you only specify the width of the column that needs to be wider (i.e. 1 in each of those tables), you'll probably end up with a layout that works out perfectly well.

As for using inline CSS, it's considered bad form to mix content and styles, and you really should keep all your styles in stylesheets. If you feel that your CSS is getting bloated, try to figure out what styles can be compressed because they are the same, such as:

```
td.foo, td.bar { width: 40%; }
```

Thus, when you need to modify the display of one page element, your styles remain consistent across your site.

Comment: Thanks! Hope the rest of the CSS goes smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try combining table columns that have the same properties and remove all the redundant declaration:

```
.stuff, .this, .that { width: 10%; }
```

Comment: I did consider this - wanted to see if others thought it might work too. :)

Comment: One of the best parts of CSS is being able to define the styles for multiple selectors at once. It should be used extensively :) Also, as Myles said, you should use Less.js, not to combat bloat, but to allow you to be more expressive with your CSS - check out http://lesscss.org/

Comment: this method is good for reducing bloat, but less so for maintainability, although it is easy to move one class to another listing that has the percentage you want or just create a new percentage.

Comment: Jason, it's great for maintainability! If two objects are using the same styles but different selectors, they should use the same style block in your CSS file. If the appearance of one needs to branch, then you split them, but until then your styles are clean and easy to update.

Comment: @ddagradi, it's not TERRIBLE for maintainability, but i meant if you wanted to change the value in there (instead of just moving the class) you could do a bit more damage than you realize.